# Tridion 2011 adding fields to a security group

Tags: 2011

How would I add a field on the general tab of a group?

Comment: Can you add some more to this question, it doesn't really explain anything about what you need to do, or what you've tried to resolve your issue

Comment: The problem is: OP wants to add more data to a group object. The solution is probably UI extension + AppData.

Comment: I have some ideas on working with extensions but not sure where to start with Appdata. Seems like good information is hard to find and most of these modifications that I want to add should be easy.

Comment: "should be easy."  typically they are but you must first have a lot of understanding of how the CMS GUI interface (anguilla) framework is built.  It's quite a steep learning curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tridion 'FBI' project is still under development, it contains some great examples of:

- Extending the GUI
- Using the 'Extension XML'

you can check it out here: https://code.google.com/p/tridion-field-behavior-injection/

I'd recommend to install it, and review:

1) How the extension is 'hooked into the schema and component dialogs' - you'll need to do this in your security dialog

2) How form fields and field groups are injected into the diaglog

3) How this information is stored (extension XML) into the CM database.  If it's not possible to use extension XML with non-content items, then here you're best best to to look into custom 'app data'

i hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

Julian Wraith has a post about GUI extensions that might help you further.

http://www.julianwraith.com/2010/10/helloworld-extension-for-tridion-2011/

I do agree with Johnwinter that additional information would be nice to help you any further.